# how to do limitation on user content post

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to do limitation on every user for posting the content only 5 times per day.

```
{
    _id: 5a3a67b102d9d926f8cd66b8
    groupname: 'Testing',
    member: [
        {userid:123},
        {userid:456},
        {userid:789},
        {userid:879}
    ]
}
```

Actually, I have an approach i.e

```
First create the column which may be named as entries_counter, after that every entry did successfully, we have to increment the counter till it 5. After 5 we will stop doing the entries. And every day at night or some time format we will update the entries_counter value to 0 through CronJob.
```

Suggest me some Best or predefined/Prebuild approach which would be efficient for handling these types of situations. Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Upon posting, do a query that counts the number of posts created by the user in the past 24h hours. if it exceeds your MAX_POSTS_ALLOWED, don't allow it.

In my opinion you should not be explicitly tracking the number of posts created each day. Or you will be needing to clear the column each day.

Comment: According to the clear a column on each day, there is some problem regarding the time format. Every country has their different timezone. So let's say the I would like to clear column on 23.59 then how it can be possible because every timezone is different

Comment: Anyways thanks at least you will try to figure it out.

Comment: @Iron_Man on your server, all dates should be on the same time zone.

Comment: Ohh.. Actually that I don't Know. So what time format i have to store. Unix One is I think the Perfect one??